# Springboot websocket testing with Postman

Tags: spring-boot, testing, websocket, postman, java-websocket

I'm trying to test a SpringBoot websocket using Postman. I'm able to successfully connect Postman to the endpoint, but I can't figure out how to test a topic subscription.
I've got a pretty standard websocket config:

```
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

The connection to `/ws` endpoint works fine:
[image]
Now I'd want to test a subscription to some topic `/topic/x/y`, just as I'm doing in the Angular frontend, but I didn't find any useful info about this, not even in Postman docs.
Could such thing be done? And, if it could, how?

Comment: For now Postman does not support STOMP, only RAW. So for this day you can connect and send message without any additional methods (subscriber, publisher, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

We can connect from postman Once the we socket request establish we have to do subsequent events also

1. establish connection using CONNECT event for connect event we get Knowlagent from server heart beet [image: CoonectEvent]
2. Then You have to Subscribe the Destination to listen for messages
   [image: Subscribe]
3. Once subscribe you will get the message from server
4. Send message using this SEND event[image: SEND messsage]

for the NUL character:

```
postman.setGlobalVariable("NULL_CHAR", '\0');
```

Then, whenever you need to use it for WS, just call the variable with {{NULL_CHAR}}