# Spring Boot End Points are not routing correctly using STOMP

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I was running into some issues in terms of getting Postman to correctly send messages over my web-socket via STOMP. I made a new project to do some testing and I am having a hard time understanding why my messages are not being sent over.

```
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket");
        registry.addEndpoint("/gs-guide-websocket").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080").withSockJS();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I registered two endpoints. The first end point is being used by Postman. To clarify this code actually works, I have tested it with SockJS() as a fallback and it works as expected.

For the Web Socket connection via Postman, I am using ws://localhost:3000/gs-guide-websocket, which it successfully connects to. However, when sending messages via Postman, it appears as if it's lost and is never correctly handled by the MessageMapping method as seen below.

```
    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public MessageResponse send(Message message) throws Exception {
        return new MessageResponse(message.getContent());
    }
```

I am confused through where my messages are actually being sent to, if anywhere at all. I have tried reading through Postman documentation to no avail. Is there a mistake somewhere in my code where I am not correctly handling this sort of end point or is this an error on Postman's part?

Link to the guide I am using for testing: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Answer (score 0):

From countless hours of researching this problem, it seems like Postman does not support the websocket process that STOMP requires.

From a comment via: [Springboot websocket testing with Postman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70081840/springboot-websocket-testing-with-postman)

For now, Postman does not support STOMP, only RAW. There is currently not any way to subscribe to a topic.

The problem I was having is that it can connect to the WebSocket without a problem. However, you are unable to send a message to the correct route at this given time.

For testing your WebSockets, I would recommend using JS/TS to perform operations. This is because you are able to subscribe to a topic via Stomp.over(socket).