How do I access a STOMP Websocket with Postman?
Hello I am trying to create a simple Web Socket using Spring Boot. It seems that Spring boot seems to require STOMP so I have the following...
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat");
        registry.addEndpoint("/topic/messages");
    }
}
@Controller
public class ChatController {

    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        Thread.sleep(1000); // simulated delay
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(message.getName()) + "!");
    }
}

However, when I try to use postman to call I can connect, but I can't subscribe to the topic. I can get everything to work with the following node script...
import { Client } from '@stomp/stompjs';
import { WebSocket } from 'ws';

Object.assign(global, { WebSocket });

const client = new Client({
    brokerURL: 'ws://localhost:8024/chat',
    onConnect: () => {
        client.subscribe('/topic/messages', message =>
            console.log(`Received: ${message.body}`)
        );
        client.publish({ destination: '/app/chat', body: 'First Message' });

        client.publish({ destination: '/app/chat', body: 'Second Message' });
    },
});

client.activate();

But is there a way I can use headers or parameters to connect, send and subscribe to the actual topics using Postman?

Have you tried the steps in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78251280
